# kotlin: assigning class data member create problem

Tags: android, kotlin, android-recyclerview

I have two kotlin files - one is recycler_adapter(fragment) and another is fragment_B i want to send data to fragment_B.

**Problem**: why tag4 (inside getdata() function) not printing anything?.

Searched every possible query but not find solution.

Adapter:

```
override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: dashboard_viewholder, position: Int) {
    val currentitem = sampledata[position]

    Glide.with(holder.itemView).load(currentitem.imageResource)
            .placeholder(R.drawable.ic_baseline_history_icon)
        .into(holder.imageView)


    holder.textView.text = currentitem.text1
    holder.itemView.setOnClickListener {

        service_providers_list().getshared_data(currentitem.text1) //calling function

        val appCompatActivity = it.context as AppCompatActivity
        appCompatActivity.supportFragmentManager.beginTransaction()
            .replace(R.id.Activity_frag_container, service_providers_list())
            .addToBackStack(null)
            .commit()
    }
}
```

> let say currentitem.text1 = 'apple' (string type)...............................
> Fragment code(below)

```
   class service_providers_list(): Fragment(){
    var sdsd = ""

    fun getshared_data(text1: String) {
        this.sdsd = text1
        Log.e("tag1", text1) // this print apple
        Log.e("tag2", this.sdsd) //this print apple
        Log.e("tag3", sdsd) //this print apple
        getdata()
     }

     override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
        getdata()
        service_list_recycler = service_provider_recycle_view.findViewById(R.id.service_provider_recycle_view)
        service_provider_recycle_view.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(this.requireContext())
        service_provider_recycle_view.setHasFixedSize(true)
    }

    fun getdata() {
        
        Log.e("tag4", sdsd) //this print nothing.   why??
        {.............code for database............}
     }
}
```

Comment: Probably `sdsd` is still an empty String by the time `onViewCreated` gets called. I don't see you calling `getshared_data` before `getdata`.

Comment: this.sdsd = text1 should assign it, and I called getshared_data from adapter. if I call it from fragment i have to pass text1 which i dont have.

Comment: Just looking your code, you create different  `service_providers_list` when click and invoke `getshared_data()`. and it's not related with `service_providers_list` where in `replace()`.

Comment: The adapter is not going to be calling any functions until after the Fragment’s `onViewCreated` is called. Regardless, if your adapter is calling functions on the Fragment, there is a kind of a design flaw in how you’re structuring your code. That’s inversion of control. The adapter shouldn’t have to know how to do anything besides connecting data to views. You can pass listeners to it for it to fire when it’s buttons are clicked. The fragment can define those listeners. This prevents your code from having too much coupling, which makes it over-complicated.

Answer (score 0):

It is just easy way in your code, but not best.

```
setOnClickListener {
    val yourFragment = service_providers_list()
    yourFragment.arguments = Bundle().apply {
        putString("YOUR_KEY",currentitem.text1)
    }
    val appCompatActivity = it.context as AppCompatActivity
         appCompatActivity.supportFragmentManager.beginTransaction()
             .replace(R.id.Activity_frag_container, yourFragment)
             .addToBackStack(null)
             .commit()
```

and in `service_providers_list`

```
override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
    sdsd = requireArguments().getString("YOUR_KEY")
    //...
}
```

You can learn good way in your situation looking below post. or there are many good posts in internet.

https://medium.com/androiddevelopers/for-my-next-trick-i-will-write-about-onclick-45e0a6881c8a

Comment: got this error-------'service_providers_list{e9b8c12 (bd0dc7b1-bdd7-4d22-880e-5c05ce9349da) id=0x7f080001} does not have any arguments.'

Comment: Would you update your all code that you tried?